# Prevent sending referrers when clicking links from my site with an exception for one domain

Tags: apache, iis, policy, http-referer

Let's admit that, for security or privacy reasons, I want to globally set my [referrer policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) to be `"no-referrer"`.

For instance, using Apache's `.htaccess`'s

```
Header always set Referrer-Policy no-referrer
```

or IIS' `web.config`'s

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Referrer-Policy" value="no-referrer" />
             </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In other words, I want this policy to be globally enforced, for every single webpage, and I enforce this policy at the level of the server.

However, for one particular domain (say `https://validator.w3.org/`), I'd like to send the referrer (for instance, to use the convenient `url` `https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer`).

I could use the experimental [`referrerpolicy` attribute of links](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-referrerpolicy), but I don't know how well is that attribute supported. I don't know either if such an attribute can override the setting of the server.

The `link type 'norefferer'` attribute [seems to be well supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=referrer), but I want to achieve the opposite!

How could I globally disallow the referrer to be sent, except for links pointing to a particular domain?

---

Disclaimer: (a variation of) that question was posted on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/109954/54133). Despite a bounty, it had only 100 views in 2 weeks, and only [one answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/110130/54133) was offered. That answered is more a "proof of concept" than anything else, and does not cover the "*does it override the server's configuration?*" aspect of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `Referrer-Policy: no-referrer` header will instruct the user agent not to send a `Referer` header at all, there is little you can do without touching the delivered content. In a usual scenario, the server has no knowledge what kinds of links the content holds, and the options for `Referrer-Policy` header only deals with the origin of the request.

The only viable option I come to think is to rewrite content. Since the `noreferrer` attribute is widely supported you could use [Apache's mod_substitute](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_substitute.html), for instance.

You would need to formulate a suitable regular expression to match links that you want to include the `noreferrer` attribute to. Something like `<a\s+[^>]*href="(http://)?www.google.com[^"]*">`will match `a` tags pointing to google homepage.